# Mariadb malloc configuration- tcmalloc vs tcmalloc_minimal

Tags: mysql, mariadb

I am using mariadb 10.4. Initial sysbench test showing promising result with `tcmalloc`. But much better result(TPS & Latency) is obtained using `tcmalloc-minimal` which basically removes heap checker (http://goog-perftools.sourceforge.net/doc/heap_checker.html) and heap profiler (http://goog-perftools.sourceforge.net/doc/heap_profiler.html). Can someone help with any functionality impact or disadvantage of using tcmalloc-minimal instead of tcmalloc?

Also I have added THP disabled configuration. but google suggested THP enabled with tcmalloc. Any suggestion over this?

Comment: THP vs non-THP - recommend look though [this article](https://alexandrnikitin.github.io/blog/transparent-hugepages-measuring-the-performance-impact/) that has perf counters, background discussion and a generic practical example. To quote the conclusion "Do not blindly follow any recommendation on the Internet, please! Measure, measure and measure again!". This will also vary depending on kernel version. Love to see your test case and results too.

Comment: Thanks Dan. I am testing it extensively & will post